# Optimal replacing windowTitle with new QString

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing Qt-based application and need to update MainWindow title each time a user changes an active document. The title is build as follows: "AppName - DocumentName".

If I understand correctly, when I set new title via `QWidget::setWindowTitle` method, the old `QString` title is deallocated and new one is set. But it can result a lot of malloc/free calls during my application executing.

Is it possible to preallocate `QString` for the title with some spare for long DocumentName string, and after 1st `setWindowTitle` to get a reference (not a copy) to this new title string in order then only to replace the needed part in existent title, and then somehow force this updated title to be refreshed?

Comment: what version of qt are u using?

Comment: If you have performance issues with changing window title - something wrong with your GUI design. The title shouldn't be changed so frequently.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Qt 5.9.7

Answer (score 0):

you can change the title as much as you can, you dont need to free memory, just give a valid string to the method:

```
setWindowTitle(const QString &);
```

the following example changes the title setting the date and time every second:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myTimer = new QTimer(this);
    myTimer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(myTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::changeWinTitle);
    myTimer->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    myTimer->stop();
    delete myTimer;
}

void MainWindow::changeWinTitle()
{
    auto dateString{"Now: " + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString()};
    qDebug() << dateString;
    this->setWindowTitle(dateString);
}
```

Comment: My question was not to get explanation how to use the `setWindowTitle` API, but about the efficiency. I do this thing like in your example, it is very simple. But I afraid each `setWindowTitle` call leads malloc/free overhead inside the Qt engine